# Tikz "Times Roman" in axis labels

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, times

How do I set my axis labels to use Times New Roman or Times Roman fonts, please? I'm looking for something similar to:

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}}
```

which works for Sans-serif

Is there any way to find the full set of abbreviations for fonts, please?

(I have been searching for hours, but there is nothing online remotely related to this. If I've just missed it, then I apologise.)

Comment: do you load `\usepackage{times}` and `\usepackage{mathptmx}` for instance?

Comment: Typical - I just found it (seconds after I submitted my question in despair): \pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={font=\rmfamily\scriptsize}}

Comment: But `\rmfamily` is not Times...